# In-app purchases showing zero transactions in Play Console while a transaction in made

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-console, android-inapp-purchase

- While testing in-app purchases in (Alpha-release) app , I did a payment via Google Pay and payment was successful.
- I can also see `Purchase History` in Google PlayStore. Also in Play console inside `Developer Account->Order management` I can see order details of my payment.
- But in Google Play Console inside `Developer Account -> Payment Settings` I am seeing my earnings as zero with no Transactions as **You don't have any transactions yet** .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: Did you pay with a test card or o real card ?